# External XACML Policy Decision Point (PDP) for WSO2 API gateway

Tags: wso2, authorization, access-control, xacml, pdp

I am trying to configure WSO2 API gateway, Can I use external PDP(policy decision Point) like Axiomatics Policy server to implement authorization? Also want to know how this can be configured, any docs or pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The WSO2 API gateway (like any other gateway e.g. Apigee) can be used to call out to the Axiomatics Policy Server (APS).
[image: Integration between Axiomatics Policy Server and API Gateway]

Comment: https://community.apigee.com/storage/attachments/2203-axiomatics-apigee-api-gateway-integration-guide-fi.pdf